Weblogic 12.2.1.4: No secure channel available for JTS driver
I can read JPA2.1 entities from an Oracle DB using an EntityManager obtained from Toplink/Eclipselink, the default provider in Weblogic 12.2.1.4, in a JAX-RS resource @Path annotated method. And can perform write operations too using a local db tx with EntityManager.begin/commit/rollback, but always get that cryptic message: "No secure channel available for JTS driver" when I try to use CDI @Transactional or the default container managed transaction support of a @Stateless EJB.
A "secure channel" means that the jdbc driver MUST use a SSL/TLS Connection to the database server? Is this optional?
I've tried with different variations of persistence.xml with jta/non-jta-data-source and JTA/RESOURCE_LOCAL tx-type pointing to a JNDI Datasource with global transactions enabled, but always get the same result, the container managed transaction fails because of no secure channel exists for the jts driver.
Thanks in advance

You may check that the RmiJDBCSecurity  parameter is set to Compatibility in your domain configuration. Check this doc for details.
